# Creating a looping timer function in Lua

Tags: loops, timer, lua

I am trying to create a looping timer function that will send a signal every `x` seconds for `y` amount of time before turning off for `z` amount of seconds and repeat on a loop, I am totally new to programming so I am unsure what to do, I have read several tutorials but I can't understand how to program, the closet I could find was

```
require 'socket' -- for having a sleep function ( could also use os.execute(sleep 10))

timer = function (time)
    local init = os.time()
    local diff=os.difftime(os.time(),init)
    while diff<time do
        coroutine.yield(diff)
        diff=os.difftime(os.time(),init)
    end
    print( 'Timer timed out at '..time..' seconds!')
end

co=coroutine.create(timer)
coroutine.resume(co,30) -- timer starts here!

while coroutine.status(co)~="dead" do
    print("time passed",select(2,coroutine.resume(co)))
    print('',coroutine.status(co))
    socket.sleep(5)
end
```

but I believe that was for a call back function, would you be able to help, and if possible explain how the program is written, sorry for asking so much,

Comment: I don't think Lua has a good threading support yet.

Answer (score 1):

Lua is just not meant to do timing (in fact no programming language that I know of is, apart from [PLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller)-specific languages). Providing timers and events is the job of the embedding application.

So you will either have to provide your own timing API, which I assume is no option given you are "totally new to programming", or make due with a module.

There are two Lua modules that may help you out:

- [Lumen](https://github.com/xopxe/Lumen) ([API](http://xopxe.github.io/Lumen/))
- [luasched](https://github.com/SierraWireless/luasched)

I have not used either one of them, but Lumen seems more active and refined. Also since it is pure Lua and does not require any additional modules, it should be easier to set up for the beginner. And actually the very first example should provide you with enough clues to set up what you want to do.

Anyway, you might want to look for other projects to learn programming first, preferably ones that do not involve timing.